# download complete webpage for offline viewing

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I am developing an iphone+ipad application in which i need to save a webpage completely and view it offline (without internet connection). Currently i am trying to save the data of webpage by NSURLConnection but its not saving the images in the webpage. I just want to know the procedure or the frameworks to save the webpage fully. Please suggest anything that raises in your mind regarding this.
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You can download software from following site ..i am using these software and these worked for me at best result..

www.httrack.com
www.surfoffline.com

Comment: I believe he wants the apis available for iOS not a windows application.